# how to put first value in one column and remaining into other column?

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas

ROCO2_CLEF_00001.jpg,C3277934,C0002978
ROCO2_CLEF_00002.jpg,C3265939,C0002942,C2357569

I want to make a pandas data frame from csv file.
I want to put first row entry(filename) into a column and give the column/header name "filenames", and remaining entries into another column name "class". How to do so?

Comment: give a few more rows pls, is it a list that you are trying to convert into a pandas Dataframe? What do you want to do: convert a list to a pandas Dataframe, just rearrange a list?

Comment: so i assume these are 2 rows from your csv file? are there no columns headers? and to confirm the number of commas per row is not fixed? asking because you could have used pandas: pd.read_csv to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case your file hasn't a fixed number of commas per row, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = 'test_csv.csv'
raw_data = open(csv_path).readlines()

# clean rows
raw_data = [x.strip().replace("'", "") for x in raw_data]
print(raw_data)

# make split between data
raw_data = [ [x.split(",")[0], ','.join(x.split(",")[1:])] for x in raw_data]
print(raw_data)

# build the pandas Dataframe
column_names = ["filenames", "class"]
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_data, columns=column_names)

print(temp_df)

              filenames                       class
0  ROCO2_CLEF_00001.jpg           C3277934,C0002978
1  ROCO2_CLEF_00002.jpg  C3265939,C0002942,C2357569
```